# Libre Office Base Query

Tags: sql, date, libreoffice-base

I'm running a Libre Office Base database to manage my co-op's membership directory.  I'm trying to write a query to get a count of current membership, but I keep running into a SQL Status 37000, error code -16, Wrong data type: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in statement [SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Families" WHERE "Families"."Renewal Date" > '06/30/18'].

My query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Families" WHERE "Families"."Renewal Date" > '06/30/18'
```

From everything I've seen and read, that query is formatted appropriately and I've checked the table name and column name, repeatedly.

Comment: I switched from SQL to "wizard" format and set the values and such in there, then back to SQL and got this
    SELECT COUNT( "FamilyID" ) FROM "Families" WHERE "Renewal Date" > {d '2018-06-30' }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this construction for Date values

{D '2012-01-01'}

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Families" WHERE "Families"."Renewal Date" > {D '2018-06-30'}
```

the format '06/30/18' is ok only for Open Office